# Permission denied error while running maven install

Tags: java, maven, protoc

I have an IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2022.1.2 installed from Ubuntu Software app.
It is configured to use Maven wrapper. When I execute "install" on my java project (from lifecycle menu) I get two errors:

1. ```
   Cannot run program "/usr/bin/git" (in directory "/usr/bin"): error=13, Permission denied
   ```
2. ```
   --- protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile
   Compiling 1 proto file(s) to /.../target/generated-sources/protobuf/java 
   org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException: Error while executing process.
   ...
   at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/.../target/protoc-plugins/protoc-3.11.1-linux-x86_64.exe": error=13, Permission denied
   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
   ...
   ```

git test:

```
...:~$ /usr/bin/git --version
git version 2.25.1
```

protoc test:

```
...:~/Dev/.../target/protoc-plugins$ ls -l
total 4952
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 5068728 jun  6 14:24 protoc-3.11.1-linux-x86_64.exe

...:~/Dev/.../target/protoc-plugins$ ./protoc-3.11.1-linux-x86_64.exe --version
libprotoc 3.11.1
```

maven-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https://.../repository/maven-central/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.8.3/apache-maven-3.8.3-bin.zip
wrapperUrl=https://.../repository/maven-central/io/takari/maven-wrapper/0.5.6/maven-wrapper-0.5.6.jar
```

[image]

Same project on a different machine works well. Can't figure out a problem.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was: missing execute permission on a /jvm/jdk-...**/lib/jexec** file.